# Calculate area on 3D surface mesh encolosed by four arbitrary points from coordinate data

Tags: r, 3d, visualization, mesh, rgl

I have human facial data as below:

```
library(Rvcg)
library(rgl)

data(humface)

lm <- matrix(c(1.0456182e+001, -3.5877686e+001, 5.0972912e+001, 2.2514189e+001,
               8.4171227e+001, 6.6850304e+001, 8.3239525e+001, 9.8277359e+000,
               6.5489395e+001, 4.2590347e+001, 4.0016006e+001, 5.9176712e+001), 
              4)

shade3d(humface, col="#add9ec", specular = "#202020", alpha = 0.8)     
plot3d(lm, type = "s", col = "red", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z", 
       size = 1, aspect = FALSE,add=T)
```

for `lm`, four landmarks are placed on the surface of the mesh, in the following oder:
[image]

The yellow lines are drawn by hand for illustration purpose. **I wish to calculate the surface area of the quarilateral enclosed by the four red dots**, i.e., the surface area inside the yellow edges.

If surface area cannot be calculated, **I also welcome methods to calculate the area (not area of the surface of the face) of the quadrilateral.** I know one could calculate the sum of areas of triangle 123 and triangle 234. However, I my real application, I have no idea of the ordering and relative spatial position of the four points. Since I have thousands of qudrilateral areas to calculate, it is impossible to plot each quadrilateral and determine how to decompose the quadrilateral into two triangles. For example, I may accidentally pick triangle 123 and triangle 124, and the sum of these two triangle ares is not what I want.

Therefore, I am interested in either surface area or area of the quadrilateral. Solution to either is welcome. I just do not want to plot each quadrilateral and I want an area value directly computed from the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is more appropriate for [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com) because I think it's more a question about the math behind the code than the code itself.

If you are concerned about precision, you may want to use techniques for smoothing the calculated area of a mesh, like the one presented in [this](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/8/7/67/htm#B25-symmetry-08-00067) paper.

However, if you don't really need that area to really model the surface, then you can ignore the face and compute the *convex quadrilateral* area using the many [available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Area_of_a_convex_quadrilateral) formulas for that, however, the simplest one requires you to have the vectors that correspond to the quadrilateral's diagonals (which you can find by checking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083648/find-diagonals-of-quadrilateral) question)

If you decide to find the diagonals and use the simplest vectorial formula (half the magnitude of the cross-product between the diagonals), you should use the `cross()` and `Norm()` functions from the `pracma` package as R's `crossprod()` computes a different type of cross product than the one you will need.

Answer (score 2):

The `rgl::shadow3d` function can compute a projection of the quad onto the face. Then you'd compute the area by summing the areas of triangles and quads in the result. @DiegoQueiroz gives you some pointers for doing that,
plus the `Rvcg` package contains `vcgArea`:

```
quad <- mesh3d(lm, triangles = cbind(c(1,2,4), c(1,4,3)))
projection <- shadow3d(humface, quad, plot = FALSE)
```

Here's what that looks like:

```
shade3d(projection, col = "yellow", polygon_offset = -1)
```

[image: screenshot]

The projection ends up containing 3604 triangles; the area is

```
vcgArea(projection)
# [1] 5141.33
```

There are a few ambiguities in the problem:  the quadrilateral isn't planar, so you'd get a different one if you split it into triangles along the other diagonal.  And the projection of the quad onto the face is different depending on which direction you choose.  I used the default of projecting along the z axis, but in fact the face isn't perfectly aligned that way.

EDITED TO ADD:

If you don't know how to decompose the 4 points into a single quadrilateral, then project all 4 triangles (which form a tetrahedron in 3-space):

```
triangles <- mesh3d(lm, triangles = cbind(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,4), c(1,3,4), c(2,3,4))
projection <- shadow3d(humface, triangles, plot = FALSE)
```

This gives a slightly different region than projecting the quad:

```
vcgArea(projection)
# [1] 5217.224
```

I think the reason for this is related to what I referred to in the comment above: the area depends on the "thickness" of the object being projected, since the quad is not planar.

Comment: Great suggestion! I didn't think about projecting the quadrilateral onto the face, unfortunately would still need to build a mesh. I'm afraid there isn't a method to do that without partitioning the surface into simpler objects.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz: The `humface` object is already a mesh, and building one from the quadrilateral is really trivial, so this wasn't really a problem.

Comment: I know, I meant that OP seems to not realized this. Or at least I thought he wanted a way to do that without relying on a mesh

Comment: I like the idea of projection as well. It is just that the `triangles = cbind(c(1,2,4), c(1,4,3))` suggests that I still need to identify the diagonals. I think @DiegoQueiroz's suggested method of finding diagonals is useful. After identifying the diagonals, one could compute AREA following the formula suggested by @DiegoQueiroz and compute PROJECTED SURFACE AREA using @user2554330. Identifying the diagonals has to be the first step. Seems no handy function now, but @DiegoQueiroz's suggestion allow me to code by myself. Thank both of you for your contribution.

Comment: I've edited the answer to address this.